# UITableView losing height when i search

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im getting a little trouble here. I have a UISearchBar that searchs for me some content, that are included on UITableView. Perfect.

When my view loads, i set a 110 height to my table view row. Nice. When my view appears, it comes with 110 px. of height. Nice.

But when i click on UISearchBar, my rows loses the height setted.

I dont know what can be.

Any help, thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

theTableView.rowHeight = 110;
theTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


}
```

And the search code:

```
    - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
        [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
        self.theTableView.allowsSelection = NO;
        self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }

    - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
        searchBar.text=@"";

        [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
        self.theTableView.allowsSelection = YES;
        self.theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

        // All the actions goes here, like parsing xml.

        [self.tableData removeAllObjects];
        [theTableView reloadData];
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639722/uisearchdisplaycontroller-changing-row-height)

Comment: Manuel, add you answer as answer instead of comment. I almost missed your answer.